# Why does my do/while loop occasionally fail to run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, do-while

I have a do/while loop that generates two numbers between 2 and 10 and then checks their greatest common factor. If the greatest common factor is not equal to 1, it generates two different numbers until it finds two that do not have any common factors other than 1.

This runs most of the time, but about every fourth time, it fails to generate numbers. The code seems to get "stuck", but I'm not sure why:

JAVASCRIPT

```
function randomBetween(min, max) {
  var ceiling = max + 1;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling - min)) + min;
}

function GenerateRandomNumberNoCommonFactorsWithAnother() {
  var Numerator;
  var Denominator;
  var gcd = function gcd(a, b) {
    return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
  };
  do {
    Numerator = randomBetween(2, 10);
    Denominator = randomBetween(2, 10);
    gcd = gcd(Numerator, Denominator);
  } while (gcd != 1);
  return {
    Numerator: Numerator,
    Denominator: Denominator,
  }
}

var Test = GenerateRandomNumberNoCommonFactorsWithAnother();
$(".Test").html(Test.Numerator);
$(".Test2").html(Test.Denominator);
```

HTML

```
<span class="Test"></span>
<br>
<span class="Test2"></span>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/190mvbzt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gcd` name is already used by the function, so if you assign a value to it, you basically overwrite the function with the new value.

Use another name for this variable, such as `gcdResult`:

```
var gcdResult = gcd(Numerator, Denominator);
```

and adjust your `while` accordingly:

```
while (gcdResult != 1);
```

This becomes:

```js
function randomBetween(min, max) {
  var ceiling = max + 1;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling - min)) + min;
}

function GenerateRandomNumberNoCommonFactorsWithAnother() {
  var Numerator;
  var Denominator;
  var gcdResult;
  var gcd = function gcd(a, b) {
    return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
  };
  do {
    Numerator = randomBetween(2, 10);
    Denominator = randomBetween(2, 10);
    gcdResult = gcd(Numerator, Denominator);
  } while (gcdResult != 1);
  return {
    Numerator: Numerator,
    Denominator: Denominator,
  }
}

var Test = GenerateRandomNumberNoCommonFactorsWithAnother();
$(".Test").html(Test.Numerator);
$(".Test2").html(Test.Denominator);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Test"></span>
<br>
<span class="Test2"></span>
```

Comment: Make sense - Thank you for your help! I'll "accept" the answer in a few min when it allows me to do so

Answer (score 2):

You’re replacing gcd as a function with an integer. If gcd happens to return 1 the first time your loop exits but in any other scenario it will break.

Try renaming the function findGcd and declare a *separate* gcd variable to hold the number so you don’t overwrite the function.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you, Christopher!

Answer (score 0):

Your do/while loop works.

However, your gcd function doesn't always return a numeric value. Because of its recursive nature, the a % b is sometimes evaluated as a%0, which returns NaN.

You need to account for zeros before attempting the modulus.